# Pit of Radiance - A study on board games

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, board-games

[image: Pit of Radiance]
*<sup>(Click to enlarge)</sup>*
(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and most other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion+user%3A78764)) is a single word. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.
**Note:**

**Progress Check:** (Those will be the "hints")
Turn 4 (After three full turn cycles have happened)

> LegS is on Step 1
>  Aurielle is on Step 4
>  Crasseyon is on Step 3
>  Eenox is on Step 6
>  Butcher is on Step 2

Turn 7

> LegS is on Step 2
>  Aurielle is on Step 9
>  Crasseyon is on Step 0
>  Eenox is on Step 8
>  Butcher is on Step 3

Comment: A couple questions:
What number does LegS begin incrementing from?
How many spaces does one fall when they lose a duel?
Also, is that Drawful 2 I see?

Comment: LegS starts from +1, when a duel is lost, all spaces are lost (falling). And yes, some of the pics were made in Drawful

Comment: Another question. In the turn structure, duels happen before the window of activation for the Fool, so how does the Fool stop duels from happening? Either the Fool prevents duels on the _next_ turn, or the window of activation needs to be before duels take place on the current turn.

Comment: @fjix No duels can happen from a Fool card use, meaning if the player moves and ends up in a position where they would duel the next turn, they don't.

Comment: What if Aurielle must choose between multiple groups of equal size?

Comment: I have the same question as @WoomyRogue, possibly in the same place. On turn 7 (the 6,4,4,5,6,2 roll), Auri is somewhere on steps 5-9 so can see 5 dice. How do they pick the most common value when two values appear twice? Details: ROT13(Fgnegvat sebz gur cebterff purpx uvag, Nhev vf ba fgrc sbhe. 
Ghea 4 (1fg zbba pneq), Nhev cvpxf -2, zbirf onpx gb fgrc gjb. 
Ghea 5, Nhev cvpxf 3 naq zbirf (+1 sbe zntvpvna'f pubvpr) gb fgrc fvk.
Ghea 6, Nhev cvpxf 3 naq zbirf gb fgrc avar.
Ghea 7, ???)

Comment: Deepest apologies, everything should be fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took a while, and a couple of extra nudges to get the correct solution, but should now be complete.

Everyone starts on step 0.
Current positions: A:0  B:0  C:0  E:0  L:0

### Turn 1:

> Magician's choice is -1 on roll of 5
>  First roll is 6,5,5,5,2,3
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 3,2,2,2,-1,0
>  A chooses the most common value: 2
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -1
>  C chooses the lowest positive value: 2
>  E chooses the highest value: 3
>  L chooses 2 as there is no 1: 2
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  A, C and L move forward 2 steps.
>  B cannot move backward 1 step, so stays on step 0.
>  E moves forward 3 steps.
>  Current positions: A:2  B:0  C:2  E:3  L:2
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 2 back 1 step.
>  So A, C and L move back 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 1: A:1  B:0  C:1  E:3  L:1**

### Turn 2:

> A, C and L are on the same step, so must duel.
>  C always loses duels, and it sounds from L's comment like they lost a tie.
>  So A wins the duel and C and L drop back to step 0.
>  Current positions: A:1  B:0  C:0  E:3  L:0
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 4
>  Roll is 6,6,6,4,1,2
>  Without adjustment this gives steps of 3,3,3,1,-2,-1
>  A chooses the most common value: 3
>  B chooses the highest value on even turns: 3
>  C chooses the lowest positive value: 1
>  E chooses the highest value: 3
>  L chooses 3: 3
>  Four people voted for 3, which is too many. So none of them would move, except B played their Fool card.
>  B moves forward 3 steps.
>  C moves forward 1 step.
>  Current positions: A:1  B:3  C:2  E:3  L:0
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 1 forward 1 step.
>  C moves forward 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 2: A:1  B:3 C:2  E:3  L:0**

### Turn 3:

> Fool card was played, so no duels now.
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 5
>  Roll is 5,5,5,4,4,2
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 2,2,2,1,1,-1
>  A chooses the most common value: 2
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -1
>  C chooses the lowest positive value: 1
>  E chooses the highest value: 2
>  L chooses 1: 1
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  A and E move forward 2 steps.
>  B moves back 1 step.
>  C and L move forward 1 step.
>  Current positions: A:3  B:2  C:3  E:5  L:1
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 2 forward 1 step.
>  So A and E move forward 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 3: A:4  B:2  C:3  E:6  L:1**

### Turn 4:

> Moon card activated.
>  Magician's choice is -1 on roll of 3
>  Roll is 1,1,3,1,2,1
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of -2,-2,0,-2,-1,-2
>  A chooses the most common value: -2
>  B chooses the highest value on even turns: 0
>  C chooses the lowest value as none are positive: -2
>  E chooses the highest value (from first five dice): 0
>  L can't choose from his sequence, so chooses the highest value: 0
>  Three people voted for 0, which is too many. So none of them move.
>  A and C move backwards 2 steps.
>  Current positions: A:2  B:2  C:1  E:6  L:1
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 0 back 1 step.
>  So B, E and L move back 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 4: A:2  B:1  C:1  E:5  L:0**

### Turn 5:

> B and C are on the same step, so must duel.
>  C always loses duels, so falls back.
>  Current positions: A:2  B:1  C:0  E:5  L:0
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 6
>  Roll is 6,6,5,3,4,1
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 3,3,2,0,1,-2
>  A chooses the most common value: 3
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -2
>  C chooses the lowest positive value: 1
>  E lost steps so plays 0 (from first five dice): 0
>  L starts over with 1: 1
>  Two people voted for 1, which is too many. So neither of them move.
>  A moves forward 3 steps.
>  B can only move backwards 1 step.
>  E chose 0 so doesn't move.
>  Current positions: A:5  B:0  C:0  E:5  L:0
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 3 forward 1 step.
>  So A moves forward 1 step
>  **Positions at end of turn 5: A:6  B:0  C:0  E:5  L:0**

### Turn 6:

> Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 4
>  Roll is 6,6,6,5,6,5
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 3,3,3,2,3,2
>  A chooses the most common value: 3
>  B chooses the highest value on even turns: 3
>  C chooses the lowest positive: 2
>  E chooses the highest value (from first five dice): 3
>  L chooses 2: 2
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  A, B and E move forward 3 steps.
>  C and L move forward 2 steps.
>  Current positions: A:9  B:3  C:2  E:8  L:2
>  Magician's choice doesn't affect anyone as no 4's were rolled.
>  **Positions at end of turn 6:  A:9  B:3  C:2  E:8  L:2**

### Turn 7:

> C and L are on the same step, so must duel.
>  C always loses duels, so falls back.
>  Current positions: A:9  B:3  C:0  E:8  L:2
>  Empress card activated.
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 6
>  Roll is 6,4,4,5,6,2
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 3,1,1,2,3,-1
>  A chooses the most common value (closest to 0) (from first five dice): 1
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -1
>  C chooses the lowest positive value: 1
>  E chooses the highest value (from first five dice): 3
>  L chooses 3: 3
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  Empress is active so all steps are doubled
>  A and C move forward 2 steps.
>  B moves back 2 steps.
>  E and L move forward 6 steps.
>  Current positions: A:11  B:1  C:2  E:14  L:8
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 3 forward 2 steps (doubled by Empress).
>  E and L move forward 2 steps.
>  **Positions at end of turn 7: A:11  B:1  C:2  E:16  L:10**

### Turn 8.

> Moon card activated.
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 3
>  Roll is 3,3,3,3,3,1.
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 0,0,0,0,0,-2
>  A chooses the most common value(from first four dice): 0
>  B chooses the highest value on even turns: 0
>  C chooses 0 because there are five of them: 0
>  E chooses the highest value (from first three dice): 0
>  L can't choose from his sequence (from the first four dice), so chooses the highest value: 0
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone could move if they hadn't all picked 0.
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 3 forward 1 step.
>  So everyone moves forward 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 8: A:12  B:2  C:3  E:17  L:11**

### Turn 9.

> Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 5.
>  Roll is 2,2,3,5,2,6
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of -1,-1,0,2,-1,3
>  A chooses the most common value (from first four dice): -1
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -1
>  C chooses the lowest value (after choosing 0): -1
>  E chooses the highest value (from first three dice): 0
>  L starts over and chooses 2 (from first four dice): 2
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  A, B and C move back 1 step.
>  L moves forward 2 steps.
>  Current positions: A:11  B:1  C:2  E:17  L:13
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 5 forward 1 step.
>  L moves forward 1 step.
>  **Positions at end of turn 9: A:11  B:1  C:2  E:17  L:14**

### Turn 10.

> Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 5.
>  Roll is 3,3,3,3,5,5
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 0,0,0,0,2,2
>  A chooses the most common value(from first four dice): 0
>  B chooses the highest value on even turns: 2
>  C chooses lowest positive value: 2
>  E chooses the highest value (from first three dice): 0
>  L can't chooise from his sequence (from the first four dice), so chooses the highest value: 0
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  B and C move forward 2 steps
>  Current positions: A:11  B:3  C:4  E:17  L:14
>  Magician's choice moves everyone who picked 5 forward 1 step.
>  B and C move forward 1 step
>  **Positions at end of turn 10: A:11  B:4  C:5  E:17  L:14**

### Turn 11.

> Devil card activated.
>  B falls and C moves forward 2 steps. C will fall on turn 14 (but the games doesn't last that long).
>  Current positions: A:11  B:0  C:7  E:17  L:14
>  Magician's choice is +1 on roll of 5.
>  Roll is 3,3,3,4,4,2
>  Without adjustment, this gives steps of 0,0,0,1,1,-1
>  A chooses the most common value (from first four dice): 0
>  B chooses the lowest value on odd turns: -1
>  C chooses lowest positive value (from first five dice): 1
>  E chooses the highest value (from first three dice): 0
>  L starts over and chooses 1 (from first four dice): 1
>  We don't have too many choices for any value, so everyone can move.
>  B cannot move back from step 0.
>  C and L move forward 1 step.
>  Current positions: A:11  B:0  C:8  E:17  L:15
>  Magician's choice doesn't affect anyone as no 5's were rolled.
>  **Final positions at end of turn 11: A:11  B:0  C:8  E:17  L:15**

### Finding a word

> The reference to 26 steps could be a hint to use A1Z26, but the steps start from 0, so let's use A0Z25 instead.
>  (Listing the players in the order that their cards are defined):
>
> ```
>  Card      Player          Step  A0Z25
>  Fool      Butcherberries   0     A
>  Magician  LegS            15     P
>  Empress   Eenox           17     R
>  Devil     Crasseyon        8     I
>  Moon      Aurielle        11     L
> ```
>
> Which, gives us **APRIL**.

Comment: You have a small mistake on Step 10, so close !

Comment: I've stared at turn 10 for what seems like hours, and I can't see any errors. I might need a small push in the right direction.

Comment: P vf ba Fgrc 2 ng gur ortvaavat bs Ghea 10. pubbfrf 5 (+2), gura unf 1 nqqrq ol gur Zntvpvna. Lbh znqr n fznyy glcb (be pnyphyngvba reebe) naq chg P ba Fgrc 4 vafgrnq bs 5 ng gur raq!

Comment: How did I miss that? Now fixed.

Comment: The answer word is incorrect, but you've done a colossal job. A huge congrats to you!
If you want the correct word (Gur pneq beqre jvyy thvqr lbh)

Comment: Got it, yet another edit is in progress.